# Can I upgrade Windows 7 32bit to 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, licensing, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I'm about to reinstall my copy of Windows 7.

The DVD comes with 32bit and 64bit versions.

I originally installed the 32bit version and have activated it.

What I can't seem to find out from anywhere is whether I can reinstall it but use the 64bit version and will the activation still be valid?  Or do I have to buy a whole new copy of Windows 7?

Also I think there are 64bit drivers for all the devices I'm using, but are there any major applications that have problems in 64bit?

Finally, is the difference between 32 and 64bit that noticable in day to day use?  (Assuming I upgrade my RAM to say 8gb - currently 4gb).

Comment: This question should be asked in superuser.com

Answer (score 5):

The licence keys are the same for 32bit and 64 bit versions of the same edition (Home Premium, Professional, ...) of Windows 7. You only need the 64 bit installation media. You cannot upgrade between them, only perform a new installation, so backup your data.

The speed advantage of 64bit is usually neglible, the important advantage is that you can use 4GB or more RAM. 8 Gigabytes will most likely not result in a noticeable performance increase for standard usage, compared to 4 Gigabytes. If you use a lot of memory-intensive applications like virtualization, image manipulation, etc. there are very real benefits to putting more RAM into your computer.

Comment: Well, 64 bit Windows could offer a speed increase when running 64 bit native applications (most of the applications nowadays are still 32 bit), since they can take advantage of the large number or CPU registers and 64 bit operations. Of course, this will be only noticeably in CPU intensive operations like compression.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I think there are 64bit drivers for all the devices I'm using, but are there any major applications that have problems in 64bit?

Yes, a few apps will have problems but not many.

When I first got my 64bit machine, the Cisco VPN software (32bit) supplied by my company didn't work. I had to wait for the 64bit version, before I could access the company server from home. Since then, I haven't had a problem but I always install the 64bit version of apps if they are available.

Comment: VPN software is a special case for software because it normally also includes a network driver that it has to load. So in that case the VPN software is probably fine on 64-bit but they only included a 32-bit network driver.

Answer (score 0):

If your DVD comes with both 32bit and 64bit, the key will work on both copies - Microsoft wouldn't give you dud software now?

EDIT: just read the rest of your question. using 64bit will offer some speed advantages, as well as being able to store much larger numbers.

Comment: *cough* Vista *cough*

Comment: @Ignacio - _cough_ pretty much every M$ product, IMO _cough_ ;-P

Comment: *cough* putting a dollar sign in the acronym MS does not make you look clever *cough*

Answer (score 0):

> are there any major applications that have problems in 64bit?

A search should reveal any major problems, but the 64 bit OS should run 32 bit programs without any problems.

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8947/13) on the gaming site about the game Crysis. The OP experienced problems with the 64 bit version of the program which went away when he installed the 32 bit version.